# Set the text of a textbox based of a list of characters

Tags: c#, winforms, split

So I have the following form:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is the following:

After entering a name, I want the initials of the name to be generated just by clicking the initials textbox.

I have found the following method to get the first characters of a string:

```
string EngineerName = tb_Name.Text.ToString();
EngineerName.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i[0] + " "));
```

My question was, how would I assign the list of characters to the text of a `textbox`?

I tried:

```
private void Tb_Initials_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string EngineerName = tb_Name.Text.ToString();
            EngineerName.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => Console.Write(i[0] + " "));

            tb_Initials.Text = EngineerName;

        }
```

But this just fills up the text box with the exact same name...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the result of splitting somewhere. Consider this code snippet:

```
string EngineerName = tb_Name.Text.ToString();
string initials = "";
EngineerName.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => initials += i[0] + " ");

tb_Initials.Text = initials;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
private void Tb_Initials_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tb_Initials.Text = "";
        string EngineerName = tb_Name.Text;
        string[] splitted = EngineerName.Split(' ');
        for(int i = 0; i<splitted.Length; i++)
            tb_Initials.Text += splitted[i];

    }
```

Comment: `tb_Name.Text.ToString()` - Performing `ToString` is redundant on Text property which is already a string.

Comment: `tb_Initials.Text += splitted[i]` - This logic seems to have problem. Every time `tb_Initials` text box is clicked, this code will not clear the previous initials. So, e.g. if first click populated it with `PB` then on next click it will become `PBMS` when it should be `MS` So clearing the contents of the `tb_Initials` text box is required at the start of the `Tb_Initials_Click` function.

Comment: @RBT true, forgot about reseting the string, answer updated.
About the ToString, well... It was copy paste from his code :\

Comment: `tb_Initials.Text = '';` - this line of code is giving compilation error - `Empty character literal`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it directly:

```
string EngineerName = tb_Name.Text.ToString();
var initials = "";
EngineerName.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(i => initials += i[0] + " ");
//trim the extra space in the end.
initials = initials.TrimEnd();
tb_Initials.Text = initials;
```

Comment: This gave me an error `Cannot convert 'void' to 'string'

Comment: How would it help to print each letter to the console?

Comment: @KahnKah I've fixed it. Please note that you will also have to perform `initials.TrimEnd()` in the end else it will have an extra space in the end.